# OpenXML, IsolatedStorage, NETWORK SERVICE and Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, openxml, isolatedstorage

I have a large web application. One very small piece of this web application generates XLSX files using the OpenXML library (written in C#).

I've run into the problem described in this post: [IsolatedStorage Access Denied](http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Svante-Seleborg/Dates/2008/10/IsolatedStorage-Access-Denied/)

However, the instructions there are for Windows Server 2003, and the user directory hierarchy in 2008 is different.

I've tried creating the IsolatedStorage directory in these locations (and then giving NETWORK SERVICE permissions to it):

C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\IsolatedStorage

Those did not work. I've tried to find where the appropriate location for the IsolatedStorage directory is on Windows Server 2008 (generally using Google and specifically here) without success.

Can anyone tell me where I should create that directory (or alternatively, suggest some other solution that would force OpenXML to instruct the archive library to not use IsolatedStorage to create the spreadsheet)?

**Edit - July 14, 2011 - Adding the exception message and stack trace so it will hopefully help others find this.**

```
Exception: System.ApplicationException
Message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
Source: mscorlib
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.nGetRootDir(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.InitGlobalsNonRoamingUser(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetRootDir(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetGlobalFileIOPerm(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Init(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.ReliableIsolatedStorageFileFolder..ctor()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.GetDefaultIsolatedStorageFile()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.CreateUserScopedIsolatedStorageFileStreamWithRandomName(Int32 retryCount, String& fileName)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.EnsureIsolatedStoreStream()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.SwitchModeIfNecessary()
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOFileItemStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.InternalWrite(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean isAsync)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.FlushBuffer()
   at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteAttributeTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteAttributesTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlPartRootElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlPartRootElement.SaveToPart(OpenXmlPart openXmlPart)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.SavePartContents()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Close()
```

Comment: Found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx.
If the information for Vista also applies to Windows Server 2008, then the location should be either:
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\IsolatedStorage or
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\IsolatedStorage.
Accordingly I created those two directories and gave NETWORK SERVICE full control over them, and the creation of the .XLSX file still fails.

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere with trying to create directories and recreate the solution in the blog post I linked to above. Looks like my options are either to make the file smaller, or see if there is a way to force OpenXML to instantiate the archive library in such a way that it doesn't switch to IsolatedStorage.

Comment: No luck finding a way to prevent OpenXML to not use IsolatedStorage. I was able to use ILSpy to see where it's choosing whether or not to use it, but I can't see any obvious way to change the highwatermark var it uses to switch between the MemoryStream and IsolatedStorage. I did find the specific profile that the NETWORK SERVICE account uses on Win Server 2008 - it's C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService, but even creating the IsolatedStorage folders there doesn't help things.

Comment: are you sure you're seeing the same problem? on windows 2008, application pools by default use an "application pool identity" account which does not have an entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList and so the problem did not occur at all for us on 2008. If you're using network service on windows 2008 maybe you could revert to the default "application pool identity" setting.

Comment: We're using network service for this particular application. Honestly, I don't know exactly why, but my understanding is that there was a good reason that choice was made when things were set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During my research, I stumbled across this blog post as well: http://www.kevinrohrbaugh.com/blog/tag/openxml

I dismissed it at first since it's not possible for me to have my application impersonate another user, due to the way it interacts with another web application that I have no control over.

However, I got to thinking that perhaps it I got rid of the registry entry for NETWORK SERVICE in ProfileList, I could get the same result.

So, I renamed HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-20 to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-20-backup and re-ran my Excel export and it is working properly. As far as I can tell I don't have any negative results from having done this.

Answer (score 0):

[I would have added this as a comment, but I don't have permission...]

I hope this helps someone else...

I have an app running in IIS Express as Network Service on Windows Server 2008 R2.  The isolated storage store that is returned from calling IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForDomain() is located at: c:\ProgramData\IsolatedStorage